# How can I store Hindi characters in python list?

Tags: python

I want to store some hindi words in a python list and print those hindi words using list indexing.

Comment: Use unicode-encoded strings: ` print u'हलो'`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `u` prefix to the string to specify unicode

```
>>> [u'स', u'भ', u'ी', u'म', u'न', u'ु', u'ष', u'्', u'य', u'ो', u'ं']
['स', 'भ', 'ी', 'म', 'न', 'ु', 'ष', '्', 'य', 'ो', 'ं']
```

In Python 3.x you don't even need to do this, however, because it used unicode encoding by default.

Comment: In Python 2 it's possible to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` then one doesn't need the `u` prefix.